# How to load the data of component in advance Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to load the data of my `http` request before the user even opens that component.

```
  this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(list => {
      console.log('List: ', list);
      this.productList = list;
    });
```

The reason is that this request takes a bit long response, so as a result it slows down the application performance. Is there any method to load this data in advance without knowing the user, so that when user visits the component, he doesn't have to wait that long.

Comment: Assuming that you're using ionic 4, you can use `resolve` to do this, you can read about the [**Angular Router Resolve**](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) from here.

Comment: Yes, for this you can use [Angular Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), good example is [here](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the request when the service loads and then save the response on the service. ie:

```
class ProductService {

  let products: Array<Product>;

  constructor () {
    this.getProducts.subscribe((products: Array<Product>) => {
      this.products = products;
    });
  }

}
```

then in your component, just reference `this.productService.products;`

If you expect that the request still will not have returned by the time the component is loaded, then you could set up a subject that is resolved when the getProducts call returns. Then subscribe to that in your component.

```
class ProductService {

  let products: Array<Product>;
  let productsLoaded: Subject<Array<Product>> = new Subject();

  constructor () {
    this.getProducts.subscribe((products: Array<Product>) => {
      this.products = products;
      this.productsLoaded.next(this.products);
    });
  }

}
```

then in your component:

```
public ngOnInit () : void {
  this.productList = this.productService.products;
  if (!this.products) {
    this.productService.productsLoaded.subscribe((products: Array<Product>) => {
      this.productList = products;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use this pattern, you should use a subject instead of an event emitter. Event emitters are only for handling events in components, and should not be considered a substitute for subjects.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @DwayneHua.
But when should I invoke my service then ? As soon as the app starts ?

Comment: Its better here to use ReplaySubject and there is no need to check `if(this.products)` or create `let products: Array<Product>;`. Just put `public productsLoaded: ReplaySubject<Array<Product>> = new ReplaySubject<Array<Product>>(1);` and subscribe to it